# Add new Output and Resource to existing AWS CloudFormation Stack

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

We have a previous stack with some resources and outputs, and we want to add new resources, but when we add a new environment variable that reference a new stack output and we try to deploy with serverless we found that:

serverless deploy --stage Zzzz

`Trying to request a non exported variable from CloudFormation. Stack name: "Xxxx-Cognito-Zzzz" Requested  variable: "MyNewVariable".`

I have the following .yml:

```yaml
environment:
    MY_NEW_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE: ${cf:${self:custom.serviceName}-Cognito-${self:custom.stage}.MyNewVariable}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CloudFormation console:

- Select the stack which you need to update.
- Click on update action
- Select the current template
- Update the template with the new configuration env variables (or any other settings like the instance sizes)
- Update the cloud formations settings.

Now go to your EC2 dashboard: (please be careful here, specially if you are in the production environment)

- Select the instance which was created by the cloud formation stack and terminate it.
- In a while youll see the new instance spawn, with the updated configurations. This should have your env variable.

Note: It is recommended to have at least 2 instances in the cloud formation stack so that you don't face a downtime in the production environment. Once you delete the instance the traffic will be migrated to the other instance until your new instance is spawned and reaches a steady state. Once this is done, the other instance can also be terminated so that it can be replaced as well.

Comment: Is possible to do only with serverles?? is any way to do automactically?

Comment: I think if you did not use cloud formation, then it would have been easily possible. Since cloud formation is implemented its is going to enforce the creation of all resources according to the template defined. I shall update you if i find a better answer!